# postgresql jsonb_path_query strange result

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath

`SELECT jsonb_path_query('[1,2,3,4]' :: jsonb, '$')` returns

| jsonb_path_query |
| --- |
| [1, 2, 3, 4] |

which sounds good.

`SELECT jsonb_path_query('[1,2,3,4]' :: jsonb, '$ ? (@ <> null)')` returns

| jsonb_path_query |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

I would rather expect the same result as the first query because this second result corresponds to the jsonpath `'$[*]'` or this one `'$[*] ? (@ <> null)'`.

What did I miss in the jsonpath language and that could explain this second result ?

Comment: Might as well be a bug.

Comment: Simple nest your array in an other one to get your *expectation*. `SELECT jsonb_path_query('[[1,2,3,4]]' :: jsonb, '$ ? (@ <> null)')` The observed result is for sure *unexpected*, but the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html) says nothing about the result in this case (except for `To retrieve the contents of an array, you typically use the [*] operator`) - so I'll not call it a *bug*. Is there a *real use case* behind?

Comment: Thanks @Marmite for your comment. There is a real use case behind this question. I reported a bug on the postgres web site and will share the answer in this post.

Comment: [BUG #17440: not expected result from jsonb_path_query](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/17440-b8f554829089cf0f%40postgresql.org)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Alexander Korotkov :

> The default jsonpath mode is lax.  Lax mode automatically unwraps
> arrays.  Unwrapping array in filter affects the result value as well.
> Strict mode works as you expected.
>
> SELECT jsonb_path_query('[1,2,3]' :: jsonb, 'strict $ ? (@ <> null)')
> [1, 2, 3]
>
> My personal opinion is that lax mode is generally prone to
> javascript-style weirdness, and one should always use strict.

see [his original answer](https://postgrespro.com/list/id/CAPpHfdsjdwArnbGoChhehd_d_T16of7APhpigK0MhZ13xMp1Pw@mail.gmail.com#head)